# Is there any way to tweak / rotate mouse orientation? Any applications? Registry edits?

Tags: windows-7, logitech-mouse

I've got a very frustrating issue with my new Logitech Marathon Mouse M705. It is absolutely perfect for what I need, with the exception that it tracks on an angle for some reason.

What I mean is when you slide the cursor to the left, it trends upward - when you slide to the right, it trends down. Moving the cursor along a flat horizontal line is no longer a natural motion - you need to fight what I suspect is a mechanical error of some kind. Unfortunately, I've already exchanged this mouse once and tested both on different Windows 7 and Mac OS X machines - the problem continues to occur.

Is there a software solution for me? I'm incredibly surprised there is no simple way to adjust the orientation... how can every mouse manufacturer possibly adjust their hardware to track to everyone's tastes? What about those who need to flip orientation a full 90 or 180 degrees? I only need to adjust mine a few degrees, but I'm sure that need has arisen as well.

Anyway, I'm running the latest SetPoint drivers (6.00) on Windows 7 and there are no orientation options available. I've checked out [uberOptions](http://uberoptions.net/) and the M705 isn't supported yet (with the last version update over 6 months ago). [MAF Mouse](http://www.maf-soft.de/mafmouse/) instructions are a very strange series of mouse clicks to activate. This app also seems a little overkill and costs $$ (which I'm willing to pay as a last resort).

Is there no universal registry value for mouse orientation? How about for SetPoint drivers specifically? I've done a simple search in regedit without any luck. An XML file somewhere? Anything?

Comment: The Microsoft IntelliPoint stuff once came with the option of calibrating the mouse direction. But I haven't seen it for quite some time now.

Comment: Yeah, I guess Logitech MouseWare drivers used to have orientation options as well, but that was for use with older hardware.

What gets me is that I guess if you hook up a trackball with SetPoint, orientation options become available!

It's in there! Let me use it!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [SakasaMouse](http://hp.vector.co.jp/authors/VA026826/) to set the angle you want on your mouse.
I use it for my Performance Mouse MX.

[image]

Downside: It seems to make my mouse less accurate.

Comment: Coming back wayyy late, but this looks like exactly what would have been useful at the time. I actually ended up selling my mouse, but maybe this answer will be useful to anyone else in the same position!

Comment: I recently started having rsn complaints due to mouse clicking. switched to a vertical mouse and started using it close to my stomach, which caused orientation side-effects. now I dont have to write my own fix thanks to this!

Answer (score 0):

Try holding the mouse at a different angle. What is "left" relative to your desk is not necessarily "left" relative to the mouse, and because a mouse is far from rectanglar it can be hard to tell its intended orientation.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion - I actually tried this first. Unfortunately, this goes against the ergonomics of the device, making it uncomfortable to hold, and inevitably slips back into the "natural fit" for my hand anyway. :\